# Как найти общие общие символы строк?

Tags: c++

Дано две строки, одна выводится рандомно, ну или на выбор пользователя вводится им же, и вторая строка которая через клавиатуру также нужно вводить (первая строка ещё может быть или только из чисел,букв или вообще любых символов).
Нужно найти общие символы строк и заменить их на '#', и ещё вывести кол-во раз сколько оно повторяется.
Вот сам код :

```
void foo1(string stroka2, string stroka,int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < stroka2.length(); j++) {
            if (stroka[i] == stroka2[j]) { 
                stroka2[j] = '#'; stroka[i] = '#'; }        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Что не так?
У меня программа работает в таком виде, этот результат вам подходит?[image: В данном случае программа заменяет совпадения на пробел]

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo1(string str, string str1)
{
   for(int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++)
       for(int b = 0; b < str1.length(); b++)
           if (str[a] == str1[b]) { str[a] = ' '; str1[b] = ' '; }
   cout << str << "\n" << str1;
}

int main()
{
    foo1("Adder", "Read");
}
```

Comment: Кароче я просто уже туплю, всё работает, спасибо большое))

Comment: не забудьте поставить галочку @Quadath!

Comment: Какая галочка? Я за это не отвечаю.. 13 лет, а уже людям помогаю)